# Spinner não mostra item selecionado

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um private List estados = new ArrayList();
estou preenchendo ele corretamente e exibe os valores no Spinner mais quando eu seleciono ele muda o tamanho como se tivesse selecionado mais não exibe o conteúdo.
Ex: correto seria isso

spinner = "SP"

fica assim no meu 
spinner = "  "

meu spinner no xml

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnersexo_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtsexo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"/>
```

meu código para add os valores no spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,estados);
    adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    EstadoUsu.setAdapter(adp);
```

Minha class

```
 public class Cadastro_Usuario extends Activity {

EditText NomeUsu, FotoUsu, NascimentoUsu, SenhaUsu, TelefoneUsu, CelularUsu, EmailUsu, CepUsu, EnderecoUsu, NumeroUsu, ComplementoUsu, BairroUsu, CidadeUsu;
Spinner SexoUsu, EstadoUsu;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<String> estados = new ArrayList<String>();
private String estado;

private String tag_json_obj = "jobj_req", tag_json_arry = "jarray_req";
private String TAG = Cadastro_Usuario.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_usuario);

    NomeUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtnome_usu);
    SexoUsu = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnersexo_usu);
    NascimentoUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtdata_usu);
    NascimentoUsu.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##/##/####", NascimentoUsu));
    SenhaUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtsenha_usu);
    TelefoneUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttelefone_usu);
    TelefoneUsu.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("(##)####-####", TelefoneUsu));
    CelularUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtcelular_usu);
    CelularUsu.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("(##)#####-####", CelularUsu));
    EmailUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail_usu);
    CepUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtcep_usu);
    CepUsu.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##.###-####", CepUsu));
    EnderecoUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtendereco_usu);
    NumeroUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtnumero_usu);
    ComplementoUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtcomplemento_usu);
    BairroUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtbairro_usu);
    CidadeUsu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtcidade_usu);
    EstadoUsu = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerestado_usu);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    RetornaJSONEstado();

}

private void RetornaJSONEstado() {
        showProgressDialog();
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Const.URL_JSON_ARRAY_CAD_USU,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();

                    int aJsonint = 0;
                    String aJsonString;

                    // Recupera seu adapter
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = (ArrayAdapter<String>) EstadoUsu.getAdapter();

                    // Desabilito a notificao por enquanto, ate terminar de adicionar tudo
                    adp.setNotifyOnChange(false);

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonarray = response;
                        JSONObject jsonobj;

                        for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
                            jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                            aJsonString = jsonobj.getString("sigla");
                            aJsonint = jsonobj.getInt("id");
                            System.out.println("ID " + aJsonint + " sigla  " + aJsonString);
                            // Voce pode adicionar aqui, mas nao eh recomendado
                            //estados.add(aJsonString);

                            // Adiciono direto no ArrayAdapter
                            adp.add(aJsonString);
                        }

                        // Habilitar novamente a notificacao
                        adp.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                        // Notifica o Spinner de que houve mudanca no modelo
                        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    System.out.println("Deu ERROR PQP");
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    msgerro();
                    finish();
                }
            }
    );

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req,
                tag_json_arry);

    // Cancelling request
    // ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag_json_arry);


}

private void msgerro(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Verifique sua conexao com internet e tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.hide();
}
}
```

Meu layout completo

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/fundoverde2">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*Nome:"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="15"
        android:id="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*Sexo:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtsexo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnersexo_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtsexo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*Nascimento:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtData"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnersexo_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:entries="@array/array_sexo"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtdata_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtData"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Telefone Fixo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txttelefone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtdata_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edttelefone_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txttelefone"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Celular:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtcelular"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edttelefone_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtcelular_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtcelular"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*E-mail:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtemail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtcelular_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtemail_usu"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtemail"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:ems="15"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*Senha:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtsenha"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtemail_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/edtsenha_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtsenha"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*Estado:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtestado"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtsenha_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerestado_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtestado"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*Cidade:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtcidade"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerestado_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:id="@+id/edtcidade_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtcidade"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:ems="10" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*Endereço:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtRua"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtcidade_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtendereco_usu"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtRua"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Complemento:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtcomplemento"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtendereco_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtcomplemento_usu"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtcomplemento"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*Numero:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtnumero"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtcomplemento_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/edtnumero_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtnumero"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*Bairro:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtbairro"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtnumero_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtbairro_usu"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtbairro"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CEP:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtcep"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtbairro_usu"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edtnome_usu"
        android:textColor="#006600"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtcep_usu"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtcep"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="   Salvar   "
        android:id="@+id/btsalvar_tra"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtcep_usu"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="OnCadastroUsuario"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#009900" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Fiz a alteração que indicou e esta dando esse erro

```
09-23 11:59:26.348    2211-2211/spac.com.br.jobbroker W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-23 11:59:26.398    2211-2211/spac.com.br.jobbroker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException
    at spac.com.br.jobbroker.Cadastro.Cadastro_Usuario$1.onResponse(Cadastro_Usuario.java:102)
    at spac.com.br.jobbroker.Cadastro.Cadastro_Usuario$1.onResponse(Cadastro_Usuario.java:89)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Guilherme, não vejo muito erro nesse código. Poderia incluir o Layout completo? Vi que esta usando o `RelativeLayout`, não tem nenhum problema de sobreposição de `View's`?

Comment: vou postar o layout completo, puts então não estou conseguindo achar esse erro. Se tiver como eu melhorar esse layout ou souber algumas técnicas aceito ajuda, tenho serias dificuldades nessa questão.

Comment: Coloquei seu código no meu dispositivo e não vi nenhum erro: http://imagecurl.org/images/72620464339968940482.png. Tem algum código ou `Listener` que interage com o `Spinner`?

Comment: vou alterar na pergunta, mostrar como estou pegando add os valores no estados, pego por WebService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, entendi o erro.

Esqueceu de chamar o método `notifyDatasetChanged` no seu `ArrayAdapter`. Isso é necessário porque está adicionando os itens direto no `ArrayList` `estados`.

De forma alternativa você poderia adicionar diretamente no `ArrayAdapter`, mas é recomendado adicionar a coleção inteira, usando o `addAll` (apenas na versão 11+ do Android), porque a cada adição ele chamará o `notifyDataSetChanged`. Para adicionar individualmente, você deve usar `setNotifyOnChange(false)`, adicionar os itens usando o `add(String)` e depois voltar ao normal com `setNotifyOnChange(true)` e chamar o `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Para isso ou terá que guardar a referência para a instância criada, ou poderá pegar do `Spinner` e notificar.

O `notifyDataSetChanged` notifica o `Spinner` que o modelo mudou. Com isso ele mede novamente a `View` que fica visível (não a do `DropDown`), chamando o método `onMeasure` no `Adapter` para realizar a medição.

Logo deve:

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Const.URL_JSON_ARRAY_CAD_USU,
    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            hideProgressDialog();

            int aJsonint = 0;
            String aJsonString;

            // Recupera seu adapter
            ArrayAdapter<String> adp = (ArrayAdapter<String>) EstadoUsu.getAdapter();

            // Desabilito a notificao por enquanto, ate terminar de adicionar tudo
            adp.setNotifyOnChange(false);

            try {
                JSONArray jsonarray = response;
                JSONObject jsonobj;

                for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
                    jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    aJsonString = jsonobj.getString("sigla");
                    aJsonint = jsonobj.getInt("id");
                    System.out.println("ID " + aJsonint + " sigla  " + aJsonString);
                    // Voce pode adicionar aqui, mas nao eh recomendado
                    //estados.add(aJsonString);

                    // Adiciono direto no ArrayAdapter
                    adp.add(aJsonString);
                }

                // Habilitar novamente a notificacao
                adp.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                // Notifica o Spinner de que houve mudanca no modelo
                adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

            System.out.println("Deu ERROR PQP");
            hideProgressDialog();
            msgerro();
            finish();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Entendi so que esta dando um erro de "FATAL EXCEPTION: main   java.lang.NullPointerException " no           adp.setNotifyOnChange(false);  ae fiz um if para ver se != null e começou dar erro no adp.add(aJsonString);

Comment: http://187.45.142.241:8080/umamao/rest/estadoWs/listar o endereço que estou pegando os estados quiser fazer um teste

Comment: Preciso saber em qual local houve o `NullPointerException`, inclua a mensagem de erro do `LogCat` completo na sua pergunta.

Comment: Adicionei minha class para poder ter uma visão de como ela está

Comment: @Guilherme, esqueceu de adicionar o `ArrayAdapter` ao `EstadoUsu`. Achei que aquele primeiro código de inicialização do `ArrayAdapter` estava sendo executado. Coloque-o entre a chamada do `RetornaJSONEstado` e a inicialização do `EstadoUsu`.

Comment: Puts falha minha ter tirado... Muito Obrigado agora funcionou! ajudou muito e obrigado mesmo pelas explicações.