# Item Selecionado no Spinner não aparece no Toast

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Ao clicar no item no Spinner, o Toast não é chamado, não aparece nada.

```
public class RegistrarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView botaoVoltar;
private EditText textoCPF, textoEmail;
private Spinner spinnerCliente;
private List<String> clientes = new ArrayList<String>();
private String cliente;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static final String URL = "http://www.caixinhadosmotoristas.com.br/spinner-cliente.php";
private StringRequest request;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrar);

    botaoVoltar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.botaoVoltarId);
    textoCPF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textoCpfId);
    textoEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textoEmailId);
    spinnerCliente = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerClienteId);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    clientes.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nome"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, clientes);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = arrayAdapter;
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerCliente.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    spinnerCliente.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            cliente = spinnerCliente.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nome: " + cliente, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    SimpleMaskFormatter mascaraCPF = new SimpleMaskFormatter("NNN.NNN.NNN-NN");
    MaskTextWatcher maskCPF = new MaskTextWatcher(textoCPF, mascaraCPF);
    textoCPF.addTextChangedListener(maskCPF);

    botaoVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent voltaLogin = new Intent(RegistrarActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(voltaLogin);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema através desse link abaixo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33548/spinner-n%C3%A3o-mostra-item-selecionado

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo, remova a linha abaixo e use o arrayAdapter direto;

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = arrayAdapter;
```

No lugar do

```
cliente = spinnerCliente.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

coloque

```
cliente = arrayAdapter.getItem(position);
```

Comment: Fiz as modificações que você comentou acima e continua não aparecendo o Toast. Coloquei um System.out.println pra ver o que apareceria no console, não aparece o nome do cliente. Só aparece o erro abaixo: 07-13 16:09:30.284 11179-11225/com.caixinhadosmotoristas.caixinhamotoristasapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaaf09960

Comment: O Toast só não aparece quando eu faço através de um Arraylist, se eu fiz um Array e já setar as strings dentro dela tipo String teste[] = { "Opção1", "Opção2", "Opção3" }, desse jeito quando clico em 1 item do Spinner, o Toast aparece normalmente...